# How would i shutdown/logoff a PC(windows 10) after some amount of time without using a batch script or task scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, system-shutdown

I am in need to shutdown my PC running on windows 10 without using either of task scheduler or an batch script after some amount of time. Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a a .bat file or task scheduler?  The other option I can suggest is using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try any program like [this one](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-auto-shutdown-user-guide.html)